# Multi-Tenancy in ABP

Tags: multi-tenant, abp, aspnetzero

I'm considering using ABP / ASPNetZero for my SaaS application.

I know that it supports multi-tenancy, but it appears like the tenant setup is manual.

I would like to create an online app that when a visitor purchases registers and purchases a subscription, they will automatically become a tenant and get an entry into the tenant table.

I would like not to have to manually create a tenant when someone registers and purchases a membership.

Is this possible with ABP?

Comment: abp is a framework, it implements common features, it is difficult to adapt to all usage scenarios, you always need to write some code. : )

Comment: Ok thanks @maliming.  I had a feeling it was possible with some customization, but wanted to know if anyone has had that particular use case.

Comment: hey you ABP allows tenants create their account. you can enable Tenant registration. Or you can create a website to sell your package and after payment, you can create the tenant manually. all these scenarios are covered.

Answer (score 0):

We can allow the user to register a tenant and then create and entry into tenant table. There will be a tenant license table which will store the license purchased. The application will verify if the payment is due for the tenant, and if so, the user will be directed to payment gateway or else can user the application.

I am not sure on the features provided by abp, but the implementation flow is like the above. The catch is off you allow custom domain mapping for tenant URLs, the DNS update might take time, else, the remaining should be taken care by the above flow itself